# Dynamic filter - Jquery / Rails-4

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-4

i am unsure where it is i am going wrong, and your help would be much appreciated.

- each time i select the an item in the select drop down list (class:
  category_advert) all my options in the select drop down list (class:
  category_advertskill) all disappears
- what i would like to do is, in the first select option - when i select the category Accountancy, all subcategories under Accountancy should be displayed in the second select option

[image]

_requiredskills_fields.html.erb (form)

```
<%= f.collection_select :category_advert_id, CategoryAdvert.order(:name), :id, :name, {},  {class: 'category_advert'}  %>
<%= f.grouped_collection_select :category_advertskill_id, CategoryAdvert.order(:name), :category_advertskills, :name, :id, :name, {prompt: "Select a category"}, {class: "category_advertskill"} %>
```

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var category_advertskills;
  category_advertskills = $('.category_advertskill').html();
  return $('.category_advert').change(function() {
    var category_advert, escaped_category_advert, options;
    category_advert = $('.category_advert :selected').text();
    escaped_category_advert = category_advert.replace(/([ #;&,.+*~\':"!^$[\]()=>|\/@])/g, '\\$1');
    options = $(category_advertskills).filter("optgroup[label='" + escaped_category_advert + "']").html();
    if (options) {
      $('.category_advertskill').html(options);
    } else {
      $('.category_advertskill').empty();
    }
  });
});
```